# React Server APIs | renderToReadableStream & renderToPipeableStream reactNode to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading the documentation of [renderToReadableStream](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToReadableStream) and [renderToPipeableStream](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToPipeableStream) React Server APIs.

Their shape is the following:

- `renderToReadableStream(reactNode, options?)`
- `renderToPipeableStream(reactNode, options?)`

My question is: can **reactNode** be an *arbitrary* node (for example, a simple `<div>...</div>` tag with some content) or it should represent the entire document (`<html>...</html>`) as stated in the documentation?

Thank you!